# Monaco Editor missing icons

Tags: css, vue.js, webpack, icons, monaco-editor

The icons in Moncao Editor (0.20) are missing, they only show as blank squares in my instances. What am I missing in order to make them appear in my Vue (2.x) app?

[image: Monaco editor instance]

In Devtools > Elements, the css for :before pseudoclass looks like this for "Use regular expressions" button.
[image: Elements tab in chrome devtools]

In webpack.config.js (4.x), I have this under modules.rules

```
 { // monaco
    test: /\.ttf$/,
    use: ['file-loader']
  }
```

EDIT: In Devtools > Network tab, in the playground of [Monaco Editor's website](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html?source=v0.35.0#example-creating-the-editor-hello-world), I can see that codicon.ttf is being fetched from microsoft.github.io/node-modules/... , but in my app no .ttf files being fetched. Seems like that is the root of the issue. How can I fetch it when initializing the code editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured a solution to my own problem.

I was expecting the codicon.ttf file (which has the icons I need) to be loaded by monaco-editor from /node_modules, but it was not working. Instead, I have copied the ttf file, put it in my asset folder (or any folder where I have direct access on the client app), and call it in the vue component where I initialize the code editor.

My style tag looks like this in CodeEditor.vue:

```
<style>
  @font-face {
    font-family: "codicon";
    src: url(/app/font/codicon.ttf);
  }
  #monacoel {
    font-family: "codicon";
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that library uses `@fortawesome`. install this, since you have webpack v4

```
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.3",
```

you have to import this on top level application file

```
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css";
```

in webpack.config.js

```
{
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "svg-url-loader",
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
```

also

```
npm i svg-url-loader
```

Answer (score 0):

Is anyone has this problem when importing from a cdn, make sure to also add codicon as a style sheet

```
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vscode-codicons@0.0.17/dist/codicon.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be using `font-family: "Your font" !important` . You can Remove `!important` if it works without `!important`.